# How to decorate a LaTeX command

Tags: sectioning, numbering, counters

I've been trying to change the numbering behavior of subsection to use a global counter. I first did:

```
\newcounter{maincount}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\stepcounter{maincount}\arabic{maincount}}
```

and got:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \csname\endcsname
l.64 \subsection{Orientation}
```

I then did it by defining `\mysubsection`:

```
\newcounter{maincount}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{maincount}
\renewcommand{\mysubsection}[1]{\stepcounter{maincount}\subsection{#1}}
```

And that works fine but requires me to change every instance of `\subsection` with `\mysubsection` in the document. Is there any way to decorate a LaTeX command? As in redefining `\subsection` in a way that is able to call the previous implementation of it. This generates an infinite loop:

```
\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{\stepcounter{maincount}\subsection{#1}}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "to *decorate* a LaTeX command"? It doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: I meant in in the sense of the OO pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can copy the meaning of a macro (aka command sequence) to another using `\let\newmacro=\oldmacro` (the `=` is optional):

```
\let\origsubsection\subsection
\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{\stepcounter{maincount}\origsubsection{#1}}
```

You shoudln't put `\stepcounter` into a `\the...` macro. This makes it fragile and will might break certain `\label` or similar code.

Comment: My answer shows the general way to redefine a macro which uses its old definition. If you only want to make the `subsection` counter independent of the `section` counter then @locksteps answer is the way to go. I think I misunderstood the question because I thought `maincount` is also used and incremented elsewhere. The `main` part makes it look like it.

Comment: @Martin: Wouldn’t it be better to use `\refstepcounter` to make the count work with `\label`-`\ref`-combinations?

Comment: @Tobi: That's correct, however the `\refstepcounter{subsection}` will overwrite the label again. I didn't changed the OP original code in this point but merely wanted to show the redefinition technique. He doesn't state what exactly he is doing with it, so I kept it general

Comment: This works perfectly. As others have mentioned the way I went about this is probably not the best way to "change the count for subsections" but your solution is the correct one for "how to decorate a tex macro". Thanks

Comment: And `maincount` is indeed incremented elsewhere but I just incremented `subsection` instead and that works.

Comment: @Martin: OK :-)

Answer (score 8):

I suggest to simply use the [chngcntr](http://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr) package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{subsection}{section}

\begin{document}

\section{bla}

\section{blubb}

\subsection{foo}

\subsection{bar}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a much better solution for the numbering problem than the hack I was going for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to lockstep's answer is `xassoccnt` and its `\CounterWithout` macro, which allows for a comma separated list of counters to be removed from the driving counter reset list:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xassoccnt}
\CounterWithout{subsection,subsubsection}{section}

\begin{document}

\section{bla}

\section{blubb}

\subsection{foo}

\subsection{bar}

\subsubsection{foobar}

\end{document}
```

[image]